# Getting all sound bytes of a song in for an android app

Tags: android, audio, visualizer

I'm using the Visualizer class for creating a waveform for my app, but I would like to get all the sound bytes all at once so I can show the whole song's waveform all at once. How can I do that? Is there a function in this class I can use for this? Or is there another class for all these things I want to do? 
Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below library it will solve your problem :-

https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to all this... So may I ask how to use this? I mean, how can I use this link you gave me?

Comment: Download and import that library in your IDE and add as reference in your project. you will be able to access the functions of this library.